# How To Send a Range of Cells as a PDF in an Email with onEdit Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I create an onEdit function that allows me to send a range of cells as a PDF in an email?

Here is what I have so far:

```
function pdfEmailOnEdit(e) {

if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B2") == -1)          
  if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B3") == -1)      
    if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B4") == -1)       
      if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B5") == -1)
        if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B6") == -1)
          if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B7") == -1)
            if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B8") == -1)
              if(e.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("B9") == -1)

var email = "some@gmail.com"; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var subject = "PDF generated from spreadsheet " + ss.getName(); 
var body = "Test.";
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");
  blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".pdf");

  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[blob]     
    });  
}
```

Here is where I need help:

1. I need to make this code an onEdit function.
2. The only cells that I want to trigger the email are: B2:B9
3. The cells that I want to send as a PDF in an email are A118:H149. They must keep their formatting.
4. I only want the cells in this one sheet, not any other sheets.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: No. This code actually runs well by itself. But I am needing to add some more criteria to it, which you should be able to see in my question. That's where I am needing help.

Comment: I'd recommend that you make the required changes and return when you have some specific problems.

Comment: Ok. So I just updated my question according to my understanding of what I can do. I inserted the cells that should trigger the email (B2:B9), but nothing is happening when I edit these cells.

Comment: Then it's time for you to run the code through the Script Editors debugger and single step your way through it to figure what's not working.

Comment: I find that use of the e.source.toast is useful in debugging onEdit functions.

Comment: Hi. Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?